# Trying to create a list that counts the number primes for each remainder class

Tags: list-manipulation, prime-numbers

Considier the remainder of the first $2500$ prime numbers by the numbers from $3$ to $30$, included.

1. Calculate how many primes are in each remainder class. That is, create a list that for each number between $3$ and $30$, gives for each remainder class the number of primes in it.
   Example. the first $5$ primes are: $2,3,5,7,11$. If we consider the remainders by $3$, we have: $2,0,2,1,2$.
   That is: $1$ with remainder $0$; $1$ with remainder $1$ and $3$ with remainder $2$.

I am having trouble condensing my program because I need to create a list for each number between 3 to 30. How could I add the remainders $3$ to $30$ to my program before it counts how many primes are in each remainder class.

I shortened just to see what is happening (ie. I shortened $2500$ to $5$)

```
list = Sort[Flatten[Table[n, {n, 1, 5}]]];
PrimeQ[list];
primelist = 
Length[Select[list, PrimeQ]] ;
divide = Mod[Total /@ list, 3]; 
remainder2 = Count[divide, 2]
remainder1 = Count[divide, 1]
remainder0 = Count[divide, 0]
```

results were:

```
    {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}
    {True, True, True, True, True}
    3
    1
    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = 2500;
m = 21;
primes = Prime[Range @ 2500];

Counts[Mod[primes, #]] & /@ Range[3, m] // Column
```

[image]

If you wish you can reorganize the information above into a [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html):

```
KeyMap[ToString] /@ KeySort /@ KeyUnion[Counts[Mod[primes, #]] & /@ Range[3, m]] // 
  MapIndexed[Join[Association["m" -> ToString[#2[[1]] + 2]], 
     Association["remainderClass" -> #]] &] // Dataset
```

[image]