# finding primes using chebyshev bias

Tags: list-manipulation, prime-numbers

Using the problem from my previous question [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230860/trying-to-create-a-list-that-counts-the-number-primes-for-each-remainder-class). For each n, that is n= $10^3$ to $10^6$ with a ten-fold increase, how do I use Chebyshev Bias to display the number of primes (which are in the remainder class 1 and 3, both divided by 4)?

When I programmed it, it shows me primes starting from 7000s. However, according to [link](https://www.makethebrainhappy.com/2018/10/chebyshev-bias.html), I am not getting the same list of prime numbers. I'm not sure if I understood what they meant by divided by for $4$ for the remaining class $1$ and $3$.

```
Clear[n, m]
m = 10^n;
n = 6;
primes = Prime[Range[10^3, m]]
c1 = Counts[Mod[primes, #]] & /@ {1/4} (*remainder class 1 divided by 4*)
c3 = Counts[Mod[primes, #]] & /@ {3/4} (*remainder class 3 divided by 4*)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `/@ {1/4}` ? You just want `counts = Counts[Mod[primes, 4]];` then do `c1=counts[1]` and `c3=counts[3]`. What they mean is the primes have a remainder when divided by 4, which you get with `Mod`, and the bias is that a remainder of 3 occurs more often than 1.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I thought they literally meant to calculate the remainder class 1 and 3 by 4 so 1/4 and 3/4. Since we're only counting the number of primes, the /@ (maps) shouldn't be there. I need to review the mod[] command